# Bytes read on IOException

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

When performing a large read using Stream.Read (or FileStream.Read), if an IOException occurs (a CRC error etc.) how can I ascertain how many bytes were successfully read (i.e. at which sector did the error occur).

The Win32 ReadFile function takes a pointer to the bytesRead variable, and it would seem that this would be accurate even in the case of an error. However .NET throws an exception, giving no hint as to where the error occured.

Comment: `and it would seem that this would be accurate even in the case of an error.`? can you provide a link to the quoted source?

Comment: It is quite important that you stop running your program.  There is something *seriously* wrong with the machine, the odds that your program can continue running correctly are very low.  And worse, significant odds that you'll start creating garbage data.  Do **not** catch this error, there is no reasonable way that you can tell the user what went wrong.  You have no idea what happened and what you're supposed to do about it.

Comment: @HansPassant - your comment assumes its I'm accessing the system disk. I'm really imaging secondary drives / flash drives etc. which may have some corruption.

Comment: @kennyzx - I really have no idea if it's true. I'm wasn't quoting anyone concerning that part. However, I do plan on testing it later this month :-( on a corrupted drive (I don't have it with me currently)

Comment: In .NET you might have to work around the problem by retrying the same read with a progressively smaller size.  I ran into this in C a while back but I don't remember whether I needed to do the same thing or whether I could use `bytesRead` to determine the error location - I'll see if I can locate the source code.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - good idea, that's what I've been using until now. Please check your source! It'll save me the testing.

Comment: I found the source code I was thinking of, and it does use `bytesRead` to determine how much of the data was successfully read when an error is raised.  If I remember correctly this did work as expected.  Note that I was using asynchronous I/O, synchronous I/O might behave differently - in particular, I don't know whether a partial read will update the file pointer or not.  (Either way I recommend using asynchronous I/O for this sort of work.)